# How to install the latest gmp library in 12.04?

Tags: software-installation

I know it should be of the form "sudo apt-get install ". But what should be the name of the library? And after installing, how to verify that it has been installed correctly.

Comment: As this seems to create confusion, would you mind clarifying what exactly you are looking for?

Answer (score 61):

You can install gmp using the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

Also, check out [this post](http://www.mathemagix.org/www/mmdoc/doc/html/external/gmp.en.html).

Comment: This allowed me to update the `gmp` R package on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3):

This is the first result when googling for "ubuntu install gmp". That's why I answer such an old question.

For me the following worked:

```
apt-get install -y libgmp-dev
```